# Getting only first request responded in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, frontend, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I have 4 test cases in describe block each intercepting the same request but handling the response differently(response body is different). Interceptor(request handler function) is added the same way in each block, but only the first one returns desired data, others fail with 404.
Below one of the `it` blocks, others look very much the same.

````
it("Renders providers from core", async function () {
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);
        const requestHandler = (request) => {
            if (request.method() === "GET" && request.url() === LOGIN_METHODS_API) {
                request.respond({
                    status: 200,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        emailPassword: { enabled: true },
                        passwordless: { enabled: true },
                        thirdParty: {
                            enabled: true,
                            providers: [
                                { id: "apple", name: "Apple" },
                                { id: "github", name: "Github" },
                            ],
                        },
                    }),
                });
                page.off("request", requestHandler);
                page.setRequestInterception(false);
            } else {
                request.continue();
            }
        };
        page.on("request", requestHandler);
        await Promise.all([
            page.goto(`${TEST_CLIENT_BASE_URL}${DEFAULT_WEBSITE_BASE_PATH}?authRecipe=thirdparty&multitenancy=enabled`),
            page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" }),
        ]);
        const providers = await getProvidersLabels(page);
        assert.deepStrictEqual(providers, ["Continue with Apple", "Continue with Github"]);
    });
    ```
````

Comment: Are you using a new page or browser for each test? Ideally, tear all state down and make sure nothing leaks between tests to keep them idempotent. This isn't really a [mcve] so it's hard to help without being able to run it. `setRequestInterception` should be awaited. and `page.waitForRequest` might make more sense than `page.on` for this case. Thanks.

Comment: i have tried awaiting setRequestInterception but it was not success

Comment: Sure, because as I discussed above, there's probably a deeper design problem that's not reproducible here beyond not awaiting a promise and we don't have enough context to address. While we're waiting for that [mcve] you might consider updating to fix that bug so it doesn't call attention to itself. Thanks.